# Pass string as single argument

Tags: c#, arguments, command-line-arguments

I am trying to get a project to pass a string as an argument to another project using `Process`

If I have a string:

```
string argString = "Test Argument"
```

and I want to pass it as an argument to a second project that simply prints out the arguments that are passed to it, how do I pass that string as a ***single argument***? Meaning if I pass `argString` to my second project, I want `args[0]` to be: `"Test Argument"` instead of it breaking the string into two separate arguments separated by the space in the string.

To summarize, I have project 1 that passes a string as an argument to project 2. Inside Project 1 would be:

```
string argString = "Test Argument";
Process testProcess = new Process();
testProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = argString;
testProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"LocationOfProject.exe";
testProcess.Start();
```

And inside Project 2's main method would be:

```
Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
```

Currently this would result in project 2 printing `"Test"` instead of what I want, `"Test Argument"`. Any ides?

Comment: string argString = "\"Test Argument\""

Comment: so from the command prompt I would type project1.exe "\"Test Argument\""?

Comment: @user1806716 In the command prompt you wouldn't need to escape the quotes, or wrap a string in quotes.  To have quotes in a string in C# you need to have the whole thing in quotes (like every other string literal ever), and then use escaped quotes inside of that string.

Comment: @Servy so if I were to run my app from the command prompt and wanted to pass -f=F Argument as an argument, I would have to basically do some processing of the arguments to make sure I grab the white space between "F" and "Argument" so I treat them as part of the -f=?